# Azure Data Factory - How to drop a column in Mapping Data Flow

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I am using Excel as data source. These are my columns:

[image]

I am dropping the Attribute name in my Select transformer.

[image]

But the values are not dropped. Only the column names are dropped.

[image]

Can you please assist how can I drop the Column Attribute Name.

Thanks

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the Select activity mapping after the column has been deleted please?

Comment: It was told it is known bug. So, please ignore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one known issue in dataflow preview data with data misalignment, we had fixed it and wait for current deployment to take effective. It only impact data preview, so you can feel free to ignore the wrong data in preview and have dataflow pipeline debug/trigger run directly which can work well.